# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/user/java/8.0.181-oracle/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar while executing scala program using `sbt runMain`

Tags: java, java-8, sbt

I'm trying to run a program from SBT using `sbt runMain` command.
But I'm getting below error -

```
[error] java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/user/java/8.0.181-oracle/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar
[error]     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
[error]     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
[error]     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
[error]     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
[error]     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
[error]     at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
[error]     at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
[error]     at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:219)
[error]     at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
[error]     at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
[error]     at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2662)
[error]     at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
[error] (Compile / runMain) java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:  /home/rajkumar/java/8.0.181-oracle/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar
[error] Total time: 12 s, completed Aug 23, 2018 10:21:44 PM
```

SBT version details

```
 $ sbt about
 [info] This is sbt 1.2.1
 [info] The current project is ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/rajkumar/Coding/Java/ConcurrentProgrammingInScala/"), "concurrentprogramminginscala") 0.1
 [info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.6
```

The java version details -

```
$ java -version
  java version "1.8.0_181"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Also I couldn't find `jfxrt.jar` file anywhere within jdk folder.

```
$ find . -type f -name jfxrt.jar
```

This command return no results.

The fedora version is -

```
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
  Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)
```

Why do I get this this error? How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies with the directory structure of the Java JRE. Clearly, your `jfxrt.jar` is not where your program thinks it is, and this is because in Java 8 this jar is in the `java/<version>/jre/lib/ext/` directory as opposed to `java/<version>/jre/lib/` which is where your program is looking for it as it seems from the stack trace. One sort of hacky way of fixing this would be to copy your `jfxrt.jar` to the `java/<version>/jre/lib/` directory so it would find the file properly.

There may exist a more stable/safe solution for this, but until I (or someone else) finds this way, I would do this. Leave a comment if you have a question and I'll do my best to answer it. Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** I was searching around SO, and it appears that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123749/how-to-detect-javafx-runtime-jar-in-sbt) question should also maybe help with getting the path set correctly.

Comment: Thanks Alerra!!! your suggestion is helpful. But I couldn't find the jfxrt.jar file anywhere whithin jdk folder

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I would make sure its nowhere in there with `find` (or Mac or Windows equivalent), and if you still can't find it then I would redownload the newest stable jdk from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html